# Crack an executable in PE

Tags: windows, pe, exe

So I noticed that I can write something in PE from the executable

For example if I write 1911 he tells me

[!]Cracked By RAZOR 1911

But if I write something else it will not tell me anything. What is the reason for this?

What names or numbers are included?

Comment: Are you talking about some sort of crackme tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ProtectionID which scans the header for warez group names who like to include them in cracked executables. It doesn't recognize any string that's not a group name defined by the PID's author.

Comment: yes exactly.
How can I include a name there is my choice?

Comment: You need to modify PID to recognize your string or ask the author to include it (bad idea). Like I said, it probably only recognizes "established" warez groups.

Comment: I doubt he will put it. But thank you for your help.